# Add element to rows within a column that are in a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hello everyone I would need help in order to add element to rows within a column that are in a list.

So here is an exemple

**df**

```
COL1 COL2 
G1   Homo_sapiens_CR_bouvier
G1   Cattus_cattus
G1   Cattus_novegicus
G1   Rattus_norvegicus 
G2   Rattus_suedicus3
G2   Homo_sapiens2_CR_bouvier
```

and I any value of this list :

`liste=['Homo_sapiens','Rattus_suedicus'`]

is in the `COL2`, I want to add a tag to it such as :

```
COL1 COL2 
G1   Homo_sapiens_CR_bouvier_TAG
G1   Cattus_cattus
G1   Cattus_novegicus
G1   Rattus_norvegicus 
G2   Rattus_suedicus3_TAG
G2   Homo_sapiens2_CR_bouvier_TAG
```

Does someone have an idea please ? (the real dataframe are sometime quite huge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with add `TAG` in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
liste=['Homo_sapiens','Rattus_suedicus']
m = df['COL2'].str.contains('|'.join(liste))
df.loc[m, 'COL2'] += '_TAG' 
#working like
#df.loc[m, 'COL2'] = df.loc[m, 'COL2'] + '_TAG' 
print (df)
  COL1                          COL2
0   G1   Homo_sapiens_CR_bouvier_TAG
1   G1                 Cattus_cattus
2   G1              Cattus_novegicus
3   G1             Rattus_norvegicus
4   G2          Rattus_suedicus3_TAG
5   G2  Homo_sapiens2_CR_bouvier_TAG
```

Some alternatives:

```
df['COL2'] = np.where(m, df['COL2'] + '_TAG', df['COL2'])
df['COL2'] = df['COL2'].mask(m, df['COL2'] + '_TAG')
```